# What is the equivalent of a click in a touch screen with the finger?

Tags: single-word-requests, technology

In computing, "an act of pressing a button on a mouse or similar device is called" : **click**.

Does the action of pressing or touching the screen with the finger has a special name?

Comment: One ***taps*** on a screen.

Comment: Related: [Click or tap](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46034/word-for-click-or-tap) and similar question on [UX.SE]: [1](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/37963/what-word-can-be-used-to-mean-either-click-or-tap) | [2](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/102064/should-we-still-call-it-clicking-if-it-is-a-touchscreen)

Comment: If you are looking for a technical term, then you are better off asking on a technical Stack. The general public may *tap*, *touch*, *push*, *press*, and any number of other things.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using your finger on a touchscreen, this is usually called a ***tap***.

Comment: Except when you keep doing it it becomes a *smudge*.

Comment: A click is a tap, a double-click is a double-tap, a click and hold is (I usually hear) a tap-and-a-half (that is, tap once, and hold the second time tapping instead of lifting again).